# Problem in defining dtypes of categorical data obtained from parquet file

Tags: pandas, dataframe, parquet

There is a function inside which determines whether metadata is saved (by metadata I mean saving dtypes).  When I save a Dataframe to a parquet file and then read data from that file I expect to see metadata persistence. I will perform this check in this way:

```
In [6]:(pd.read_parquet(os.path.join(folder, 's_parquet.parquet'), engine='fastparquet').dtypes == df_small.dtypes).all()

Out [6]: False
```

```
In [7]: pd.read_parquet(os.path.join(folder, 's_parquet.parquet'), engine='fastparquet').dtypes == df_small.dtypes

Out [7]:
date              True
tournament_id     True
team_id           True
members           True
location         False
importance       False
avg_age           True
prize             True
prob              True
win               True
dtype: bool
```

If you look at the data types directly you can see the following result:

```
In [8]: df_small.dtypes

Out [8]:
date             datetime64[ns]
tournament_id             int32
team_id                   int16
members                    int8
location               category
importance             category
avg_age                 float32
prize                   float32
prob                    float32
win                        bool
dtype: object
```

```
In [9]: pd.read_parquet(os.path.join(folder, 's_parquet.parquet'), engine='fastparquet').dtypes

Out [9]:
date             datetime64[ns]
tournament_id             int32
team_id                   int16
members                    int8
location               category
importance             category
avg_age                 float32
prize                   float32
prob                    float32
win                        bool
dtype: object
```

And even if you compare the categorical data directly, you get the expected result.

```
In [10]: df_small['location'].dtypes == pd.read_parquet(os.path.join(folder, 's_parquet.parquet'), engine='fastparquet')['location'].dtypes
Out [10]: True
```

What could be the reason for this behavior?